# Why doesn't my path element inherit fill attribute that was set in CSS?

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to make a path element in SVG icon inherit fill property from the parent.

When I try set : SVG path { fill: inherit} in CSS it not inherit it but choose his inner fill property. But I don't want delete his inner fill attribute because icon become black and I need set color for every icon. Is there is something wrong I do?

```css
.contact__email-image {
  fill: red;
  path {
    all: inherit;
  }
  &:hover {
    fill: green;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg fill="none" viewBox="0 0 16 12" id="mail-black-envelope-symbol"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M14.953.252L8 6.336 1.047.252C1.332.096 1.653 0 2 0h12c.347 0 .668.096.953.252zm.79 10.71c.158-.286.257-.611.257-.962V2c0-.391-.117-.754-.312-1.062L10.691 5.31l5.052 5.652zM9.94 5.968l-1.61 1.409a.5.5 0 01-.658 0l-1.61-1.41-5.116 5.725c.307.193.666.308 1.055.308h12c.389 0 .748-.115 1.055-.308L9.939 5.968zM0 2c0-.392.117-.754.312-1.062l4.996 4.37-5.051 5.654A1.976 1.976 0 010 10V2z"  fill="#87B0EE"/>
</svg>
```

my html:

`<svg class="contact__email-image" viewBox="0 0 16 12" width="16" height="12"> <use xlink:href="img/icons/icons.svg#mail-black-envelope-symbol"></use> </svg>`

Comment: Does the demo snippet I created above show the problem? You may need to convert your SCSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do won't work because the selector cannot cross the shadow DOM. Rely on CSS variables to overcome this. Notice how I am defining the `fill` of the path using a variable with a fallback

```css
.contact__email-image {
  --color: red;
}

.contact__email-image:hover {
  --color: green;
}
```

```html
<svg class="contact__email-image" viewBox="0 0 16 12" width="40">  <use xlink:href="#mail-black-envelope-symbol"></use> </svg>
<svg  viewBox="0 0 16 12" width="40">  <use xlink:href="#mail-black-envelope-symbol"></use> </svg>



<svg fill="none" viewBox="0 0 16 12" id="mail-black-envelope-symbol" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="width: 0">
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M14.953.252L8 6.336 1.047.252C1.332.096 1.653 0 2 0h12c.347 0 .668.096.953.252zm.79 10.71c.158-.286.257-.611.257-.962V2c0-.391-.117-.754-.312-1.062L10.691 5.31l5.052 5.652zM9.94 5.968l-1.61 1.409a.5.5 0 01-.658 0l-1.61-1.41-5.116 5.725c.307.193.666.308 1.055.308h12c.389 0 .748-.115 1.055-.308L9.939 5.968zM0 2c0-.392.117-.754.312-1.062l4.996 4.37-5.051 5.654A1.976 1.976 0 010 10V2z"  style="fill:var(--color,#87B0EE)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you. I read about this method. Apparently this is the only solution for my case.

Answer (score 0):

Is this effect you're going for? It defaults to red, then changes to green on hover.

```css
.contact__email-image svg {
  fill: red; 
}
.contact__email-image svg:hover {
  fill: green;
}
.contact__email-image svg>path {
  fill: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact__email-image">
  <svg fill="none" viewBox="0 0 16 12" id="mail-black-envelope-symbol"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M14.953.252L8 6.336 1.047.252C1.332.096 1.653 0 2 0h12c.347 0 .668.096.953.252zm.79 10.71c.158-.286.257-.611.257-.962V2c0-.391-.117-.754-.312-1.062L10.691 5.31l5.052 5.652zM9.94 5.968l-1.61 1.409a.5.5 0 01-.658 0l-1.61-1.41-5.116 5.725c.307.193.666.308 1.055.308h12c.389 0 .748-.115 1.055-.308L9.939 5.968zM0 2c0-.392.117-.754.312-1.062l4.996 4.37-5.051 5.654A1.976 1.976 0 010 10V2z"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Stroke work but it not paint icon. It paint it edges only. But why fill not work the same way? When i delete attribute fill from the svg code it assept css fill property for path and paint all icon.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, your styles are using SASS / SCSS syntax (the style nesting and &:hover). If you are not using a pre-processor for your styles you need to write in normal CSS.

In CSS that would look like:

```
.contact__email-image {
  fill: red; 
}
.contact__email-image:hover {
  fill: green;
}
.contact__email-image path {
  fill: inherit; /*avoid using all unless you need it*/
}
```

Next you are using the class contact__email-image to style the SVG, but it is not present. You need to add class="contact__email-image" inside the opening svg tag. I would replace the ID with it unless you are using it.

You also have some inline fill="" code on the SVG and the path, I would remove those since they may take priority over your styles if they are being loaded with an external stylesheet file.

Comment: Yes im using pre-processor. I dont want remove fill attribute from svg code because i need it default color. I just want it to change color on hover. Can i preserve fill attribute in svg code but override it via css?